Como mantener el formato de mi texto al traerlo de la base de datos
quisiera saber como puedo presentar la información almacenada en una base de datos? A lo que me refiero, es que, se representen los espacios como en la base de datos
Ejemplo de como se almacena en la base de datos: 
'
Ana se encontraba en la biblioteca, buscando un refugio del bullicio del mundo. Entre estantes polvorientos y libros antiguos, encontró un tomo misterioso. Su portada brillaba con un tenue resplandor y las letras doradas parecían palpitar con vida. El título, "Ingreso a tu corazón", la hechizó de inmediato.
Con manos temblorosas, Ana abrió el libro. Las páginas emanaban un aroma a vainilla y canela, y las palabras parecían bailar ante sus ojos. Cada frase era un poema, cada verso una melodía que resonaba en su alma.
Ana se sumergió en la historia, un relato mágico sobre un reino de emociones donde la alegría reinaba y la tristeza era solo un lejano recuerdo. La protagonista, una joven llamada Luna, se embarcaba en un viaje para descubrir el amor verdadero. En el camino, enfrentaba pruebas que desafiaban su corazón y la obligaban a confrontar sus miedos más profundos.
'
Ejemplo de como se ven php:
'
Ana se encontraba en la biblioteca, buscando un refugio del bullicio del mundo. Entre estantes polvorientos y libros antiguos, encontró un tomo misterioso. Su portada brillaba con un tenue resplandor y las letras doradas parecían palpitar con vida. El título, "Ingreso a tu corazón", la hechizó de inmediato. Con manos temblorosas, Ana abrió el libro. Las páginas emanaban un aroma a vainilla y canela, y las palabras parecían bailar ante sus ojos. Cada frase era un poema, cada verso una melodía que resonaba en su alma. Ana se sumergió en la historia, un relato mágico sobre un reino de emociones donde la alegría reinaba y la tristeza era solo un lejano recuerdo. La protagonista, una joven llamada Luna, se embarcaba en un viaje para descubrir el amor verdadero. En el camino, enfrentaba pruebas que desafiaban su corazón y la obligaban a confrontar sus miedos más profundos.
'


Estoy utilizando PHP y Mysql, tengo la etiqueta meta charset UTF-8, también tengo el charset UTF-8 en la conexión en la base de datos y la base de datos está configurada como UTF-8.

Usa nl2br para imprimir el texto.

El problema que es de HTML en realidad. Como sabes en HTML no existen los espacios o saltos de linea con espacios y con ENTER como en los procesadores de textos.
Entonces cualquier texto que tenga espacios como finales o saltos de linea realizados presionando la tecla ENTER no se representan en HTML.
en HTML el salto de linea se realiza con la etiqueta < BR > o poniendo el texto en párrafos con la etiqueta < p > y existen otras posibilidades también.
Dicho esto. podrías tratar de identificar los saltos de linea del texto para  separar los párrafos.
Si puedes identificar los párrafos en el texto identificando los saltos de linea podrías realizar lo que necesitas.
OPCION : También podrías pensar en que cuando se almacena el texto en la base de datos darle un formato antes de almacenarlo de una forma que te permita después identificar los parrafos para mostrarlo adecuadamente en la pagina.
Si puedes identificar los párrafos en el texto identificando los saltos de linea podrías realizar lo que necesitas.
Ejemplo:
    <?php

        // si se trae los datos de la base de datos 
        //ejemplo 
        $pagina = $libro['texto'];

        //aqui cargo la variable manualmente para que se entienda
        $pagina = ' Ana se encontraba en la biblioteca, buscando un refugio del bullicio del mundo. Entre estantes polvorientos y libros antiguos, encontró un tomo misterioso. Su portada brillaba con un tenue resplandor y las letras doradas parecían palpitar con vida. El título, "Ingreso a tu corazón", la hechizó de inmediato.  Con manos temblorosas, Ana abrió el libro. Las páginas emanaban un aroma a vainilla y canela, y las palabras parecían bailar ante sus ojos. Cada frase era un poema, cada verso una melodía que resonaba en su alma.  Ana se sumergió en la historia, un relato mágico sobre un reino de emociones donde la alegría reinaba y la tristeza era solo un lejano recuerdo. La protagonista, una joven llamada Luna, se embarcaba en un viaje para descubrir el amor verdadero. En el camino, enfrentaba pruebas que desafiaban su corazón y la obligaban a confrontar sus miedos más profundos.';

        //utilizo la funcion explode para buscar los saltos de linea 
        //y separar el texto en un array
        // donde cada elemento es un parrafo del texto
        // en este casp supongo que los parrafos estan separados 
        // por el punto y dos o mas espacios ".  "
        // o puedo suponer que en la base de datos se almaceno 
        // con el salto de linea comun  ".\n"
        
        //entonces segun sea el fin de parrafo ".  " o ".\n"

        $parrafos = explode('.\n',$pagina);

        //recorro al array mostrando los parrafos en html
        //poniendo la etiqueta <p>

        foreach($parrafos as $parrafo) {

            echo "<p>". $parrafo ."</p>";

        }

        ?>

Espero que te ayude
